# JavaFx fx:id causes error

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

For some reason, my fx:id does not bind properly to my `Controller` class, and thus always causes an error.

**Controller**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Controller {

    @FXML public Button button;

    public void clickAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Button clicked.");
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <Button text="Click me!" fx:id="button" onAction="#clickAction" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
</BorderPane>
```

I think I understand the source of my problem, but I do not understand how to properly address it. According an answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134126/javafx-element-not-binding-to-controller-variable-on-fxid), I think I am trying to assign FXML elements before the constructor is called (and these elements can only be assigned during/after initialisation).

Is there a way to do this *without* implementing `Initializable`? Or am I making a completely different mistake?

Comment: Erhm, what error?

Comment: I agree. Show us your stack trace.

Comment: I just ran into something similar but somehow my Scene Builder left off `fx:` from all my Ids. I added it and was up and running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the imports

```xml
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
```

in your fxml file.

Therefore the `Button` instance created while loading the fxml file is a `javafx.scene.control.Button`.

The type of the field this is injected to needs be something a `javafx.scene.control.Button` can be assigned to.

Since your only imports in the controller besides `javafx.fxml.FXML` are from the `java.awt` packages, this is clearly not the case for the `button` field (type `java.awt.Button`).

Fix your controller to import the required classes from the `javafx` packages instead:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```

BTW: You can also leave out the parameter of the `onAction` handler, if you do not use it:

```
public void clickAction() {
    System.out.println("Button clicked.");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I guess I just hit enter without thinking when Intellij suggested my imports. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Note that:

1)You were using the old `Swing` library in the import statements

2)You need to add `@FXML` on every method and element with id defined using fxml

> Your code should be:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
     public Button button;

     @FXML
    public void clickAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Button clicked.");
    }
}
```

> Also mention that as `Fabian` and `Michael` said on their answers you
>   don't need ActionEvent actionEvent into the clickAction method.So
>   finnally:

```
 @FXML
        public void clickAction() {
            System.out.println("Button clicked.");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see if your import of ActionEvent. You are using awt and should be using javafx ActionEvent.

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent
```

> Edit 1

You also dont need to have ActionEvent as a parameter if you dont need it, just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I think I had a similar problem.
FXML was giving me error. The reason was an incorrectly imported library. 
Instead `java.scene.control` , I imported `java.awt` .

look at the possibilities:

[image]